# Save document to “Files” App permission error

Tags: ios

After opening the file in quick look(QLPreviewController), I am trying to save a document through sharing to the app "Files".
When I click "add", an alert appears "The file couldn't be saved because you don't have permission"
[image]

Comment: please add code for more clarity

Comment: provide code to more understanding..

Comment: @AryanSharma @SagarBhut , OP is using native `Files` app and he unable to save his file with this app.

Comment: @dahiya_boy You're right. But other applications such as Telegram successfully save the same file in the same way

Comment: I'm trying share from QLPreviewController